# How to pass multiple correlation value to next request in jmeter script

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, correlation

In my script i have multiple agent user and one admin .
In my script agent request for money and admin approved the money.
agent and admin has different login ids.

work flow is

agent login-> request for amount-> enter amount-> agent logout

admin login-> approved the amount-> logout

Here admin fetch the agent id(genrated by server) using correlation . 
My problem with script is this script is running for only one user(agent). as it has multiple agent and only one admin. admin get only first agent id and process for that agent id only. admin not fetching other agents ids .

thred group-
  Login agent
  request for amt
  Logout agent
  login admin
  approved the amt
  logout admin
do i need to use any coding for this or any controller ?
how can we pass multiple ids to one user ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the admin gets the ids. I'm not sure how your site works, so I can't comment too much on how you should be doing this. For instance, if admin approval is queue-based, you're going to need some kind of loop that repeatedly asks for the top approval. On the other hand, if it gets all the ids at once (probably via regex match no = 0), then you'll need to use a ForEach Loop and go through all of those variables.